# How do I install ruby gems on OS X without rails?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, mamp

I'm trying to install the capybara gem on OS X. The issue is I am running MAMP, and do not wish to run rails due to potential conflicts. How can i install a gem? Where would a Gemfile even be without a application folder?

Comment: Have you tried to install the capybara gem?  What command do you issue, and what happens as a result?

Comment: Why do you need a Gemfile? A Gem is a ruby program.  You install gems into your ruby install.  A Gemfile is a list of the names of Gems that you want to use in a project, which then can be read and installed by a program called Bundler.   You only want to install one Gem, so you don't need a Gemfile, nor do you need to install Bundler in order to install one Gem.  However, it's a good idea not to mess with your system's ruby install. So install your own ruby, then install the gem.  Check out rvm or rbenv.

Comment: I dunno, the only time i used capybara was with a gemfile, kinda assumed i needed one.

Comment: this gem contains would allow me to test a website by crawling through it, traditionally this gem is used with rails, i want to use it on a php framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what kind of conflicts you expect from running Rails app and MAMP.

But if you have ruby install on your mac then you simply can install gem with:

```
gem install capybara
```

Although I can't understand how would you use it out of rails app environment.

RVM will be definitely better.

After you will install RVM run this:

```
rvm use 2.2.0@my_gemset --create
gem install capybara
```

Comment: apparantly this installs capybara to the system rubygem which isn't recommended on os x anyone know how to go through the process of installing a seperate ruby on os x?

Comment: Do you use rvm then?

Comment: im new to os x so i don't know... i don't think so how do i check?

Comment: RVM is a ruby version management installation guide is here https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Comment: looks like a long road ahead of me... installed rvm but its not recognized in zsh

Comment: https://rvm.io/integration/zsh

Comment: sweet! give me a sec

Comment: looks like its installing properly

Comment: to see if you have rvm already installed just type `which rvm` in your terminal